# Запрос ввода из нового окна

Tags: c#, winforms

Как в Windows Forms организовать ввод данных из нового окна? При этом, нужно, чтобы введенные данные после нажатия кнопки, допустим "ОК", выводились в label Form1

Никак не пойму, окно просто закрывается, не передавая при этом данных...

Comment: Т.е. у нас есть Форм2 и из нее нужно данные в Форм1 передать?

Comment: Да, после нажатия кнопки данные должны собственно передаться и эта форма должна закрыться

Answer (score 2):

Допустим у нас есть форма. На ней поле ввода и кнопка. При нажатии кнопки устанавливается результат формы и закрывается форма.

```
public class Form2 : Form
{
    TextBox tb;
    public Form2()
    {
        this.Width = 300;
        this.Height = 200;

        tb = new TextBox();
        this.Controls.Add(tb);

        var bt = new Button() {Text = "OK", Left = 100};
        this.Controls.Add(bt);
        bt.Click += (sender, args) => {
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            this.Close();
        };
    }

    public string GetText()=>tb.Text;
}
```

Теперь как эту форму можно использовать

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    Label label;
    public Form1()
    {
        this.Width = 300;
        this.Height = 200;

        label = new Label() { Text = "Label text" };
        this.Controls.Add(label);

        var button = new Button() { Text = "press me", Top = 30 };
        this.Controls.Add(button);

        button.Click += Click;
    }

    private void Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var f2 = new Form2();
        var ret = f2.ShowDialog();
        if (ret == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            label.Text = f2.GetText();
        }
    }
}
```

Результат:

[image]

Comment: Вот это топ! Мега спасибо!

Comment: @Raccoon пожалуйста. Рад, что помогло

Answer (score 0):

Просто замените textbox на label:

```
В классе Form2 определяем свойство (или метод)

public string Data
{
    get
    {
        return textBox1.Text;
    }
}
В любом месте Form1


Form2 f = new Form2();
f.ShowDialog();
this.textBox1.Text = f.Data;

+ Противоречит не всем основам ООП
- Минусы те же
```

Источник: http://www.cyberforum.ru/windows-forms/thread110436.html#a_Q2